# Get info from URL and mysql database in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, compare

As  I tried to post in an earlier question, I am wondering how to get data from a URL and a mySQL database in php, then compare the results and if they equal each other run an event. I have this code so far, but it seems to work no matter what as long as there is an id in the URL. It never checks it against the id in the mysql database. Any ideas?

Here's the code:

```
    <?php

$random = uniqid();

if ($id = $_GET['id']) {

$dbhandle = mysql_connect('host', 'user', 'password')
 or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
$selected = mysql_select_db('a6675286_main',$dbhandle)
or die("Could not select database");

$sql = "SELECT completed FROM authentication WHERE username='admin'"; 
$id2 = mysql_query($sql);

}

if ($id = $id2) {
 mysql_query("UPDATE authentication SET completed = $random WHERE username = 'admin'");
 include 'sendmail.php';
echo "You win";
}
else {
header('Location: http://www.websites.com/');
}

?>
```

Comment: `$set_me = 'I set You';` `$equal == '';` `$identical === '';`

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you cannot decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a good PDO-related tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: I had no idea there was newer functions ive always used your "ancient" mysql functions. But truly thanks for the update because that code must be 70 years old at least.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if ($id = $id2)
```

That's wrong!

you need

```
if ($id == $id2)
```

also

```
($id == $_GET['id'])
```

Answer (score 2):

$id2 is not an id, as [mysql_query](http://se.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) returns a result set. To work with result sets of queries in PHP, please look into result functions like [mysql_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php).

Answer (score 1):

You're not comparing values in your if statements, you're assigning them
try

> if($id == $_GET['id'])

and

```
if ($id == $id2)
```

Also, you're assigning incorrect value to $id2, what you're looking for is

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$id2 = $row[0];
```

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you cannot decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: I don't see a problem with using same style and functions that the person who asked question, to make the answer more understandable to him

Answer (score 0):

Please correct:

1. `$id2 = mysql_query($sql);` You need to process the result from the $id2 array to get the variable needed.
2. `if ($id = $id2) {` ... and `if ($id = $_GET['id']) {` Use `==`

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you cannot decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: The problem is that you're encouraging bad practice. Even a footnote pointing out that PDO would be a better solution would help.

Answer (score -2):

`$id` isn't a numeric. It is a mysql resource.

```
    <?php

$random = uniqid();

if ($id == $_GET['id']) { //<-------Check this double '=='

$dbhandle = mysql_connect('host', 'user', 'password')
 or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
$selected = mysql_select_db('a6675286_main',$dbhandle)
or die("Could not select database");

$sql = "SELECT completed FROM authentication WHERE username='admin'"; 
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); //<------------ it is a mysql resource
$row = mysql_fetch_assos($result);
$id2 = $row['completed']; //<----- Now the value comes

}

if ($id == $id2) { //<-------Check this double '=='
 mysql_query("UPDATE authentication SET completed = $random WHERE username = 'admin'");
 include 'sendmail.php';
echo "You win";
}
else {
header('Location: http://www.websites.com/');
}

?>
```

- '=' is assigning operator. It means that the left operand gets set to
  the value of the expression on the right.
- '==' and '===' are comparision operators.

  - x == y (Equal)
  - x===y (Identical) It checks the type too.

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you cannot decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: `mysql_*` are deprecated and will be remove in future release.